# Cannot import TransitionProps from latest MUI version

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm using material ui `"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",` I want to import typescript inderface TransitionProps, but the eslint says the path cannot be resolved. I have the same code like in the  [material ui sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1852c?file=/demo.tsx). Only difference the sandbox is using "latest" and I have version "^4.11.3", which is the latest. What is wrong?

**eslint error**

```
Unable to resolve path to module '@material-ui/core/transitions'.eslintimport/no-unresolved
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `@material-ui/core` version `4.11.3` and I'm not seeing that error with `TransitionProps` imports. When stuff like this happens I usually go through these steps, stopping after each to see if it resolved the issue:

- Verify you spelled everything correctly (this is a good case for using copy/paste and copying the import from that working codesandbox)
- Restart the TypeScript server (in VSCode with a `.ts` or `.tsx` file open in the editor: `Shift + Cmd + P`, "Typescript: Restart TS server")
- Clean

  - Delete `node_modules` and and any build directories (ex: if using NextJS, delete the `.next` folder, if Gatsby delete `.cache` folder, etc)
  - Run yarn or npm install